Loading yaml config files twice
I am following and analyzing a code from a course on ML deployment and I found something puzzling. (This question is not related to the ML part of the code)
The ML pipeline uses some values that are in a config file. This config file is a yaml file.
This yaml file is provided to the scripts that need it through a script called core.py.
The structure of this part of the code is like this
  regression
    |
    -----config
    |      \----core.py
    |
    |----config.yml
    |
    |---train.py
    |---predict.py

So for example train.py or predict.py calls the config values through
from config.core import config or sometimes from regression.config.core import config
The core.py file is something like this
from pydantic import BaseModel
from strictyaml import YAML

class Config(BaseModel):
    value1: str
    value2: str

def ParseConfigFile()->YAML:
    # Here some code to parse the yaml file

def get_config()-> Config:
    parsed_config=ParseConfigFile()
    _config = Config(**parsed_config.data)
    return _config

config = get_config()
print(f"Config: {config}") #-> Originally it was not here

When I run the code, at first I did not notice, but after putting the print there, I notice that every time a script imports config, this makes the get_config() function gets called and the yaml read again.

Is this common or usual? Is this not costly since it is reading a yaml file? Or is there a better way to do this and loads the yaml only once? Is that even worth the effort?

And a minor question

Are from config.core import config and from regression.config.core import config equivalent?  (this project gets installed with setup.py and tox btw)


"train.py or predict.py calls the config values through from config.core import config or sometimes from regression.config.core import config". Why the different import paths "sometimes"?

@blhsing Sorry for my bad english. What i meant is that the writers of the code used the first import for train.py and the second for predict.py. And I wondered if they mean the same.

If the config file can change after the start of the program (by some execution path within the program, or by some external activity), and the changes need to be picked up without delay, then you need to reload the config file. That is independent of the config file format being YAML.
If the changes can only come from withing the program itself, it is IMO better to write out the config if changed, but keep the data in some singleton, so you don't have to re-load it from file.
Config files are usually small, but YAML is (compared to msgpack, JSON) relatively slow to load, so re-reading should be prevented when possible.
If you don't need to take others updating the config into account, you can do something like:
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

not_inited = object()

class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = not_inited
        self._file_name = 'config.yaml'

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        self.load_data()
        return self._data[k]

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.load_data()
        self._data[k] = v

    def save(self):
        if self._data is not_inited:
            return
        self.yaml.dump(self._data, Path(self._file_name))

    def load_data(self):
        if self._data is not_inited:  # cannot use None as loading an empty document gets you that
            self._data = self.yaml.load(Path(self._file_name))

    @property
    def yaml(self):
        try:
            return self._yaml
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        res = self._yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
        res.preserve_quotes = True
        # other settings like non-standard indent
        return res

    def __str__(self):
        self.load_data()
        return str(self._data)


config = Config()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('config', config)
    config['ip'] = '1.2.3.4'
    config.save()

which gives:
config {'name': 'quad-nine', 'ip': '9.9.9.9'}


Thanks. Any pointer to where can I get more info on this? Perhaps I should check singleton implementation in python?

I updated my answer. By providing a "global" instance variable that other modules use you are probably good enough to go. Please note that the recommended extension for files containing YAML documents has been .yaml since at least September 2006.
